# Как заставить $http запрос из ангуляра добиться ответа от сервера при плохом интернете?

Tags: angularjs

В СПА на ангуляре все запросы реализованы через $http. Если пакет теряется (плохой интернет) в запрос возвращается status -1. Можно ли как-то заставить $http повторять запрос, пока не будет получен ответ от сервера или определенное количество раз?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал обертку, которая посылает запросы пока не получит положительный ответ или пока количество запросов не превысит N.

Answer (score 0):

[Offline-first](http://offlinefirst.org/): с одной стороны можно [улучшить кэширование и использовать таймауты](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/guides/caching-offline), с другой - [решения для "ленивой" синхронизации](https://github.com/wspringer/angular-pouchdb) [итп](https://github.com/orbitjs/orbit-core)